# How do I restrict copy paste of text from my website?

Tags: script, website, copy-paste

I require my website to disallow copy-texting, and make it harder for others to use auto-scripting to steal information. I want to make it harder for them to steal the text. I am not a developer, so require help in layman words

Answer (score 2):

There is no real way to do this. This was asked before in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020715/disabling-copy-paste-in-a-web-page

You can use some techniques to make it harder such as disabling right-click menus and key-downs through Javascript, but anyone can then disable Javasicript. You can make your text images, but you can then use OCR programs to get it out.

There will always be a way around this, so all you can do is make it trivially harder.

Answer (score 0):

Chose your poison:

- As long as your text is text, you can't stop copy-paste.
- If your text is actually an image, the user experience will suffer

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not post the information on the public world wide web.

If you do post it publicly, web browsers can access the information, and people can do things with that information.  This is what happens when you use open standards, such as the standards used for the world wide web.

The alternative is to distribute information a different way.  For example, publicly post an executable file that decrypts information and displays it, so that people can only access the information using the program.

Still, realize that if people were to take a photo of the information, your software won't be able to stop it.  If people can see or hear, then they can record.